# Error with python Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new in python. so, I tried to show image in my tkinter project. But I continuously received this error. I searched for a lot of codes in Google but everything was out of my league.

```
###################################################
from tkinter import *

##################################################
StartScreen = Tk()
##Photo Car##
PhotoCarRed = PhotoImage(file="D:\Projects\Python\Practice\1.png")
PlacementPhotoCarRed = Label(StartScreen, image=PhotoCarRed)
PlacementPhotoCarRed.pack(side="top", fill=X)
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Try using forward slashes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
"D:\Projects\Python\Practice\1.png"
```

into

```
"D:\\Projects\\Python\\Practice\\1.png"
```

a single backslash `\` acts as a escape character. So you can see in your error that the program reads your paths as `"D:\Projects\Python\Practice .png"`, which is wrong.

Comment: @tazbirul.mbec Glad to be of help! If you feel like your question has been answered, feel free to accept the answer. :)

Comment: i tried but stackoverflow is not giving me permission to accept your answer. By the way, your ans worked for png extention but it is not working for jpg

Comment: @tazbirul.mbec Do you see the same error, `Couldn't open xxxxx.jpg: no such file or directory`?

Comment: "couldn't recognize data in image file"--> this error is showing

Comment: PhotoCarRed = PhotoImage(
    file="D:\\Projects\\python\\Practice\\galaxyhead.jpg")

Comment: @tazbirul.mbec then the issue you have now is different. You can look [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/66xte8/why_does_this_tkinter_code_open_png_but_not_jpg/) or **if you cannot find a solution** then post another question.

Comment: thank you again for your help dear. you are really humble and awesome